# Is it possible to boost mlt queries in solr?

Tags: solr

Specifically if I'm doing a query using the solr mlt handler (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler) and stream.body to supply the source doc is there any way to boost result documents based on document age?

I already know how to do that for a regular query using dismax (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Date_Boosting) but I can't quite figure out the magic incantation to do it for the mlt handler.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mlt handler is written to handle one of two cases:

1. `q=[typical query goodness which can include date boosting]`
2. `stream.body=[url]`

If `q` is present, `stream.body` is ignored and vice-versa, so unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to do what you want in a single call without patching the MoreLikeThisHandler.

---

BUT:  If you need this in a hurry, you can do it with two queries

1. Run your same MLT query solely for the purpose of retrieving the interesting-terms and boosts (e.g with `mlt.interestingTerms=details&mlt.boost=true&rows=0`)
2. Using the interesting-terms and boosts from (1), run a standard Solr query (non-MLT) with the date-boosting function you desire.

Comment: Is there any patch available for this purpose ?