# How can you add a formula scoring boost to a Solr "More Like This" query?

Tags: solr

I'm doing a "More Like This" query on 3 text fields, but I'd like to also boost the results based on a numeric "views" field. In a normal query I'd add a boost term like "{!boost b=scale(sqrt(views),1,2)}" or something similar, but this doesn't seem to work if I specify it in the mlt.qf field. Is formula based boosting allowed in MLT queries?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [More Like This](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) page on the Solr Wiki, the `mlt.qf` field allows for boosts.

> Query fields and their boosts using the same format as that used in [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin). These fields must also be specified in mlt.fl.

Checkout the syntax for boosting with the [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) and you should be able to get the boosting you desire.

Also, check out the answer to this previous question - [Is it possible to boost mlt queries in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677872/is-it-possible-to-boost-mlt-queries-in-solr)